# Can you put a bounty on a question you answered?

Tags: support, bounty

I answered a question - [How many Jedi (Knights) lived in the galaxy before The Clone Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-many-jedi-knights-lived-in-the-galaxy-before-the-clone-wars/10315#10315)  but the answer was not complete. I don't think there's any canon info to improve the answer (I researched pretty thoroughly), but I'd like to incentivise people to help verify that as I could be mistaken.

However, when I went for the obvious solution - offer a bounty - I couldn't find a bounty link.

Is that because I have an answer to that question? (It would make sense, since the bounty, if awarded to my answer, would basically offer me "free 50 rep" if I understand the bounty mechanics correctly).

The reason I wanted a bounty was because I'm afraid someone would refrain from attempting to answer the question due to an existing answer, which at first glance SEEMS to answer fully - the gap is very subtle.

Any extra ideas to overcome the concern are welcome - should I post "the gap" as a separate question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can put a bounty on a question you've already answered.

But you'll have to wait for two days to pass since the question itself was first asked [before being able to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Even if you do, you can't get rep from that bounty (there is no extra rep thrown in either).

If your answer is the one that wins the bounty, you'll get back a big fat **+0** at the end with the following note:

> this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation